# error window is not defined for defining a dynamic variable in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a dynamic variable in node js like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
    window["t" + i] = i;
}
```

but the error happens:

> (node:1300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: window
>   is not defined

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to refer a `window` variable, but it doesn't exist, at least not in this context. Note that NodeJS runs on the server, so if this code tries to refer to the `window` object known at the client-side, then it will fail doing so.

The issue has nothing to do with creating a dynamic variable, for example:

```
window = {};
for (let i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
    window["t" + i] = i;
}
```

should run without errors, but you probably want to refer to a specific `window`.